# Использование большого количества памяти при шифровании

Tags: c#, .net, aes, .net-7

Есть такие методы для шифрования и перезаписи файлов

```
    private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] fileData, byte[] key, byte[] salt)
    {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt, 10000))
            {
                aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            }

            aes.GenerateIV();
            byte[] iv = aes.IV;

            using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encryptedStream.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
                encryptedStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                byte[] encryptedData = encryptedStream.ToArray();
                return encryptedData;
            }
        }
    }

    public void EncryptFile(string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        byte[] encryptedData = Encrypt(data, key, salt);

        using (FileStream encryptedFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            encryptedFileStream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Файл {filePath} был успешно зашифрован.");

        data = null;
        encryptedData = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

И такие методы для расшифровки и перезаписи файлов

```
    private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, byte[] key, byte[] salt)
    {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt, 10000))
            {
                aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            }

            byte[] iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedData, salt.Length, iv, 0, iv.Length);
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData, salt.Length + iv.Length, encryptedData.Length - salt.Length - iv.Length))
            using (MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    cryptoStream.CopyTo(decryptedStream);
                }

                byte[] decryptedData = decryptedStream.ToArray();
                return decryptedData;
            }
        }
    }

    public void DecryptFile(string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        byte[] decryptedData = Decrypt(encryptedData, key, salt);

        using (MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream(decryptedData))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                decryptedStream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Файл {filePath} был успешно расшифрован.");

        encryptedData = null;
        decryptedData = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

И у меня такой вопрос, нормально ли что при запуске процесса шифрования директории весом в 200мб, используется около 700мб ОЗУ, но при последующих операциях используемая память не увеличивается, и не уменьшается. Т.е как будто остается зарезервированная память которая была выделена при первой операции, и после этого она используется для всех последующий операций, это нормально, или все же у меня в коде есть утечка памяти ?

Comment: Вы считываете файл целиком и храните зашифрованные данные в памяти тоже целиком. Во-первых, это немножко бессмысленно, а во-вторых, если понадобится зашифровать файл в сотни гигабайт, то будет ой

Comment: просто перепишите код, чтобы он сразу писал в файл, а не `MemoryStream`, тогда и памяти будет выделяться меньше, т.к. не нужно храниться зашифрованный/расшифрованный файл в памяти

Comment: @ExplodingKitten сейчас попробую

Comment: Переписал код без использования MemoryStream и с очисткой памяти которую предложил @CrazyElf ,
И протестировал разные варианты, шифрования, получил такие результаты. 
Шифрование с использованием MemoryStream и без очистки памяти - потребление памяти от 1.6-3.8 гб.
Шифрование без использованиея MemoryStream и без очисткой памяти - потребление от 1-2 гб.

Шифрование с использованием  MemoryStream и с очистки памяти - потребление от 0.8-1.6 гб.
Шифрование без использования MemoryStream и с очисткой памяти - потребление от 0.3-0.7 гб.

Comment: Подозреваю, вы всё ещё что-то где-то читаете целиком, потому что это всё равно очень много

Comment: Ничего больше не считывается, можете сами глянуть : https://github.com/air2921/FileCrypt

Comment: `byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);` - мне понадобилось всего пять секунд, чтобы найти на гитхабе место, в котором вы опять храните файл в памяти целиком https://github.com/air2921/FileCrypt/blob/1d00a139a38d70b853057ef3e9b75cdec290525d/FileCrypt/EncryptData.cs#L42

Comment: Посмотрел ваш код в репе. Не используйте никогда `File.Exists` или `Directory.Exists` (вообще, совсем). Первое, потому что между проверкой на существование файла и обращением к нему, даже если это очень короткий промежуток времени, файл может исчезнуть или стать защищенным для чтения/записи и т.д. А зачем вам такая проверка без гарантий? Операционка многозадачная. Лучше правильно обрабатывайте исключения при обращении к файлам. Второе потому что метод `CreateDirectory` отработает исправно независимо от того, существует она или нет, читайте документацию по методу.

Comment: Хорошо, я учту это, и обработаю исключения без использования сторонних методов, спасибо за ответ на главный вопрос, и за указание общих недочетов кода в репе.

Comment: Да, кстати, уберите вызовы `GC`, везде. Дайте сборщику свободу.

Comment: Увидел, что у вас .NET 7 (указывайте версию в будущих вопросах), переписал код на более современный C#, и немного оптимизировал. Для хэширования пароля снизил количество итераций до 1000 (стандарт), но поставил более сильный хэш. Это должно поднять общую производительность кода и уменьшить потребление ресурсов. Не забудьте расшифровать зашифрованное перед внесением изменений.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание что нужно указывать версию, просто во всех вопросах что читал, почти никто не указывал версию, также спасибо за то что не еще раз переписали методы шифрования/расшифровки в соответствии с версией шаблона. Также я  подкорректировал код  На счет использования Directory.Exists, методы которые проверяли файлы и директории, и вызывались почти везде я удалил, и вместо них обрабатываю исключения, Но вот от использования Directory.Exists в методе CreateBackup, я отказаться не смог, как мне кажется без него там в принципе никак.

Comment: Подсказка по синтаксису, у вас есть `if(_key == null) { return _key = getValue.GetKeyValueFromConfigurationFile(); } return _key;`, это можно [заменить](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) на такое `return _key ??= getValue.GetKeyValueFromConfigurationFile();`, что технически является эквивалентом изначального кода. Кстати `public byte[] GenerateKey()` - [ключ 256 бит](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.keysize), а не байт. Что там по памяти и скорости получилось?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, теперь буду знать что такое можно использовать (_key ??= getValue.GetKeyValueFromConfigurationFile();). На счет ключа, я почему то не заметил что у меня в таком случае выходит 2048 битовый ключ, xD, исправил все, теперь ключ получается 256 битовый.
На счёт скорости и потребления памяти, выходит такое : (Папка весом в 5.1гб шифруется за 23 сек, и потребляет 0.1гб, с расшифровкой почти тоже самое, только расшифровывается уже за 16 сек).

Comment: Вообще заметил что цифры каждый раз разнятся +- 20 сек может быть. Также при первом шифровании результаты по времени другие : 1 минута 21 секунда, при повтором шифровании, выходит 20-35 сек.

Comment: Скорость сильно зависит от скорости носителя, откуда берутся файлы. Повторное обращение к файлам возможно идет через кеширование внутри самой файловой системы, поэтому быстрее получается. Память стабилизировалась - это хорошо. На самом деле, здесь еще можно найти что оптимизировать, но ощутимого прироста вероятно не будет. Например можно развязку сделать потока шифрования, чтения и записи на диск с помощью Producer/Consumer. С размером буфера у `FileStream` можно поиграть, и т.д. типа поднять скорость увеличив потребление памяти. Но это уже совсем другая непростая история.

Comment: Не думаю что стоит так запариваться ради небольшого прироста, если учитывать что было до вашей помощи, то данный прирост уже очень ощутим. Дальнейшая оптимизация ради нескольких процентов как мне кажется не будет сильно ощутимой и не окупит затрат времени и сил. Спасибо за всю вашу помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно просто перестать грузить все данные целиком в память.

```
private static void Encrypt(Stream source, Stream target, byte[] key)
{
    using var aes = Aes.Create();
    byte[] iv = aes.IV;
    target.Write(iv);
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new(key, iv, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
    {
        aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
    }

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(target, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    source.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
}

public void EncryptFile(string filePath, byte[] key)
{
    string tmp = $"{filePath}.tmp";
    using (var source = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (var target = File.Create(tmp))
    {
        Encrypt(source, target, key);
    }
    File.Move(tmp, filePath, true);

    Console.WriteLine($"Файл {filePath} был успешно зашифрован.");
}
```

Этот код ни одного лишнего килобайта памяти не съест, так как в принципе не будет полностью вычитывать содержимое файла в память.

Дальше по образу и подобию.

```
private static void Decrypt(Stream source, Stream target, byte[] key)
{
    using var aes = Aes.Create();
    byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
    source.Read(iv);
    aes.IV = iv;
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new(key, iv, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
    {
        aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
    }

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(source, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    cryptoStream.CopyTo(target);
}

public void DecryptFile(string filePath, byte[] key)
{
    string tmp = $"{filePath}.tmp";
    using (var source = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (var target = File.Create(tmp))
    {
        Decrypt(source, target, key);
    }
    File.Move(tmp, filePath, true);

    Console.WriteLine($"Файл {filePath} был успешно расшифрован.");
}
```

Лишнее повыкидывал. Готово. Можно хоть фильмы по 40 Гигабайт весом шифровать, потребление памяти при этом не вырастет.

Возня с солью не нужна, на её роль прекрасно подходит рандомный `IV`. Это никак не снижает безопасность шифрования, а скорее наоборот, вам не придется везде хранить или хардкодить эту соль.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте собирать мусор так:

```cs
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

Если я правильно понимаю, по умолчанию `GC` не сжимает [кучу больших объектов](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap), потому что это занимает довольно много времени. Он просто помечает занимаемое большими объектами место как пригодное к переиспользованию и потом это место реально используется под новые объекты. И если не повезёт и сначала будет создан объект поменьше, а потом побольше, то среда исполнения будет держать как будто занятым место под оба эти объекта суммарно. Но дальше уже занимаемое место не будет расти, если новые объекты будут умещаться в это суммарное место.

А вообще рекомендуется не заниматься самодеятельностью и не вызывать `GC` вручную. Разве что у вас есть какие-то критичные по времени операции и вы хотите, чтобы `GC` обязательно отработал до этих операций, а не в какое-то случайное, не удобное для вас время. Ну или если вам нужно стараться не занимать программой память, когда она не нужна. Т.е. когда программа всё время висит в памяти, а функции эти работают не всё время, а с большими промежутками, тогда это имеет смысл, если нужно освободить память для других программ.

Comment: `GC.Collect()` использовать не стоит. Совсем. Этот код можно было исправить так, чтобы он вообще ничего не жрал по памяти, а вы предложили воткнуть костыль.